# How to crop an image after taking it in one activity

Tags: java, android

I have code that launches the camera in my android device from there, I want to add the functionality for the activity to be able to crop the image as the user wishes to.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final int CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE = 100;
private Uri fileUri;

static final int REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE = 1;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //Creating the onClick Listener for the Scan Button
    Button scanButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ScanButton);

    scanButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){

            //Creating an Intent to take a picture and return control to the calling application.
            Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

            //Launching the intent.
            startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    });



}
```

}

Comment: try this sample code on github..........https://github.com/IsseiAoki/SimpleCropView

Comment: @WaqarYounis can you provide me an example on how to use it?

Comment: just download code from github and run it...

Comment: @WaqarYounis I want to implement be able to include it in my project thats why. I havent been able to run it.

Comment: ok send me you email id send you code...

Comment: @WaqarYounis Sorry never mind. I was able to download and use the code. Thank you. Is there any more libraries you know of?

Comment: try this... https://github.com/jdamcd/android-crop and also https://github.com/cesards/CropImageView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would use another `Intent` the same way you captured the picture.

```
Intent crop = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
crop.setDataAndType(URI_OF_PIC_FROM_LAST_INTENT, "image/*");
crop.putExtra("crop", "true");
...
startActivityForResult(crop, REQUEST_CROP);
```

Replace the `URI_OF_PIC_FROM_LAST_INTENT` and `REQUEST_CROP` with your own values.

[Here's an example with more detail.](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/capture-and-crop-an-image-with-the-device-camera--mobile-11458)

You can specify things like the aspect ratio, etc. through the intent as well.

Comment: What type of values would go inside those paramters?

Comment: @JosephM `URI_OF_PIC_FROM_LAST_INTENT` should be the Uri of the image from your activity result for the `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` `Intent`. In your `onActivityResult()` method for the image capture there should be a returned `Intent`. You can call `getData()`  on it to get the `Uri`. You will have to check if it is returning the image itself or a `Uri`. The `REQUEST_CROP` is a `static final int` code for the activity just like `static final int REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE = 1;`, but with a different number obviously. Did you read the link I posted? It has a complete step by step guide...

Comment: Yes I read and followed through with the guide. I noticed however that the crop tool is only a square and does not allow the user to make a rectangle. Is this something else I need to code?

Comment: @JosephM hmm, not sure. Maybe try modifying the X and Y aspect ratios? `cropIntent.putExtra("aspectX", 1)` & `cropIntent.putExtra("aspectY", 1)`. Setting them both to 1 might result in a square but maybe change one of them to get a rectangle? Again, I've never done this so I'm just speculating at this point. Hope that helped!